# does a Yahoogroups api exist?

Tags: scripting, open-source, yahoo-api

Do we have a yahoogroups api?

I have a yahoo group and I want that whenever my RSS feeds are updated, a message should be automatically posted to the group with the link to the post.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no public API for Yahoo! Groups. If such an API is ever opened up, the Yahoo Developer Network (developer.yahoo.com) will have all the details.

Disclaimer: I work at Yahoo in the YDN group.

Answer (score 0):

I had a conversation with someone from Yahoo a few months ago - he said they were working on an API for their groups, but it was not yet ready for release. I have not heard anything since, and I don't know what their timeline is for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a JSON API for getting data out of a Yahoo! Group. See [Yahoo! Groups - Archiveteam](https://www.archiveteam.org/index.php?title=Yahoo!_Groups) for more information.